# HERE maps for JavaScript API: Calculate distance from Polygon to marker

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I have plotted few markers and a polygon objects on Here Map.

I want to know the distance between the polygon and marker. Marker that is very nearer to polygon is what I want to figure out.

Here map has a distance function, but its only working to calculate distance between 2 markers.

Here is the function that I used to calculate distance **`PaohaIsland.getGeometry().distance(yosmitePark.getGeometry())`** Where **PaohaIsland** is ***marker*** Object and **yosmitePark** is ***polygon*** object

[image]

```
var map; 
function loadMap(){

    platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'apikey': HEREMAP_KEY
    });
    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object:
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    map = new H.Map(
      document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
      defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
      {
        center: { lat: 37.278419, lng: -119.674072,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1 },
        zoom: 8
      }
    );
    // Enable the event system on the map instance:
    var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

    behavior.enable(H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM);
}

function addPolygonToMap() {

  var lineString2 = new H.geo.LineString();
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.278419,lng:-119.674072});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.335224,lng:-119.30603});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.529331,lng:-119.198914});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.522789,lng:-118.99292});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.627281,lng:-118.87207});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.80978,lng:-119.053337});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:38.01347,lng:-119.143982});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.965851,lng:-119.770203});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.898689,lng:-120.18219});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.867802,lng:-120.341492});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.746819,lng:-120.239861});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.51844,lng:-120.07782});
  lineString2.pushPoint({lat:37.278419,lng:-119.674072});

  var yosmitePark = new H.map.Polygon(lineString2, {
      style: {
        strokeColor: '#829',
        lineWidth: 8
      }
    });
  map.addObject(yosmitePark);

  var lakeMcClure = new H.map.Marker({
      lat: 37.6373862,
      lng: -120.3448606
  });
  lakeMcClure.setData("lakeMcClure");

  var Stockton = new H.map.Marker({
      lat: 37.9729404,
      lng: -121.4419639
  });
  Stockton.setData("Stockton");

  var Monolake = new H.map.Marker({
      lat: 38.0067483,
      lng: -119.1013779
  });
  Monolake.setData("Monolake");

  var PaohaIsland = new H.map.Marker({
      lat: 38.000514,
      lng: -119.0416587
  });
  PaohaIsland.setData("PaohaIsland");

  var WalkerLake = new H.map.Marker({
      lat: 38.7010578,
      lng: -118.878652
  });
  WalkerLake.setData("WalkerLake");

  var Bakersfield = new H.map.Marker({
      lat: 35.3208963,
      lng: -119.1587737
  });
  Bakersfield.setData("Bakersfield");
  var SanFrancisco = new H.map.Marker({
      lat: 37.7576793,
      lng: -122.5076405
  });
  SanFrancisco.setData("SanFrancisco");
  map.addObjects([lakeMcClure,Stockton,Monolake,PaohaIsland,WalkerLake,Bakersfield,SanFrancisco]);


  var mapObj =  map.getObjects();
  console.log(yosmitePark.getGeometry());
  console.log(PaohaIsland.getGeometry().distance(yosmitePark.getGeometry()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method in the API to calculate distance from point to polygon.

In order to achieve this, you can calculate distance from the point to each segment of the polygon's exterior LineString and then choose the smallest calculated value:

```js
function distanceToGeoPolygon(geoPoint, geoPolygon) {  
  let lineString = geoPolygon.getExterior(),
      minDistance = Infinity;

  // check distance for each LineString segment of the polygon
  for (let i = 0; i < lineString.getPointCount() - 1; i++) {
    let segmentStart = lineString.extractPoint(i),
        segmentEnd = lineString.extractPoint(i + 1),
        distance = distanceToSegment(geoPoint, segmentStart, segmentEnd);

    // set new min distance
    if (distance <= minDistance) {
      minDistance = distance;
    }
  }

  return minDistance;
}
```

here is method to calculate distance from point to segment:

```js
function distanceToSegment(point, segmentStart, segmentEnd) {
  // first we find the intersecting point of line which 
  // crosses the given point and is vertical to segment (start - end)
  let y0 = point.lat,
      x0 = point.lng,
      y1 = segmentStart.lat,
      x1 = segmentStart.lng,
      y2 = segmentEnd.lat,
      x2 = segmentEnd.lng,
      a = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1),
      b = y1 - a * x1,
      b0 = y0 + 1/a * x0,
      xi = a * (b0 - b) / ((a * a) + 1),
      yi = a * xi + b,
      intersectingPoint = new H.geo.Point(yi, xi); 


  // if calculated intersecting point is within the segment,
  // calculate distance between intersecting point and given point 
  if ( (xi > x1 && xi < x2 || xi > x2 && xi < x1) && 
    (yi > y1 && yi < y2 || yi > y2 && yi < y1) ) {
      return point.distance(intersectingPoint)
    } else {
      // else calculate distance between segment edges and given point
      // and return the smaller one
      return Math.min(point.distance(segmentStart), point.distance(segmentEnd));
    }
}
```

test:

```js
// test: (result is 14359)
console.log(distanceToGeoPolygon(lakeMcClure.getGeometry(), yosmitePark.getGeometry()));
```

**Note**: Above script returns positive numbers for points inside polygon too. If you don't want that, you can use [H.Map#getObjectsWithin](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/api_reference/H.Map_.html#getObjectsWithin) to verify if given Marker object (must be placed on map) is inside geo polygon (in your case I assume you don't need it).

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv5xyk8r/) example. It logs distance in the console after clicking on Marker object.